# Determine whether class is an EJB or not - bytecode analysis

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, bytecode

I am working on a bytecode analysis project. I am using ASM library for the same. For one of the requirement, I need to determine whether .class is a EJB or Non-EJB. Since EJB has various versions, we are trying to write logic as fool proof as possible and question may feel strange. I am well aware it may not be possible to automate completely. I am trying to follow roughly these steps:

**For EJB 2.x**

- First check if class extends a specific interface like `EJBHome`, `EJBLocalHome` etc
- Check if it has a specific methods like `ejbActivate()`, `ejbPassivate()`,`ejbRemove()`
- To check if it is a session bean, check if it implements `SessionBean` interface.

etc, etc

**For EJB 3.x**

- I think EJB 3.x is easier compared to EJB 2.x generations because of annotations.
- I can check annotations like `@Stateless` to check if it is a stateless bean
- Check annotation `@Stateful` to check if it is a stateful bean.
- Or check if `@Remote` annotation exists

etc etc..

These are the some of the ways I am thinking to check if `.class` is an EJB or not. My question is, is there any other way to check if any class is an EJB, I mean am I missing any  important thing? Please be aware that I don't have much experience in EJB.

Also is there any chance that ASM library provides this option?

Comment: For EJB3, I think the only options are `@Stateless`, `@Stateful`,  `@Singleton` and `@MessageDriven`. I think `@Remote` on it's own does nothing, because you still need some of the annotation mentioned before. But I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish. If you want to check for resources which are container managed, then you may want to check for all annotations from the `javax.ejb` package. There's for example `Timer`, which is technically not an EJB, but managed by a container's timer service.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj.. hmm yes, even I am thinking same :)